# Jest, test multiple Angular libraries at one time

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-cli

I am new to Jest (using angular-presets) and I am trying to test all the angular libraries in our project at one time.

**What I hope to accomplish:**
I want the command `ng test` to run all my tests, both the application tests and the library tests.

**What is happening:**
 'ng test' only the application tests. In order to run the library tests, I need to run each library test suite separately.

```
 $> ng test lib1
 $> ng test lib2
 $> ng test lib3
 $> ng test lib4
   and so on.
```

This takes forever to run manually because we have 18 libraries. It still takes too long to run the test to have a script that in sequence.

**Question**
Is there any way to run **all** my test with a single angular cli command `ng test`?

Comment: What version of the CLI are you running? With the latest version (8+), simply running `ng t --watch=false` will run unit tests on all projects and libraries in an angular project.

Comment: @R.Richards we are using 7.3.9

Comment: I find `ng t --` works across all projects/libs, but `ng t -- --watch` only runs tests in the default project. It reacts to file changes in other projects/libs, but then doesn't detect those changed files to test. I use ng 9.1.9 and jest for tests.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Jest for Angular. And it works very well for main source code and lib inside projects folder. Then It generates a report for you.
You can read the configuration guide [here](https://itnext.io/how-i-do-configure-jest-to-test-my-angular-8-project-2bd84a21d725).